# A PageView needs the parent to have a defined height. How can I accommodate the parent height to the PageView content?

Tags: flutter

Basically I'm trying to implement a `PageView`, as I understand I must define a height in the parent of the`PageView` to work. In the gif you can see that if I don't define the height an error appears in its parent, but if I define a height the error disappears.

[image]

The `Text("hola")` elements in my actual code will be dynamically generated, so I can't define a fixed height. In fact you can see that if I put a height, another error appears because the height of the content of the `PageView` is greater than what I defined. (`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`)

How can i solve this problem?

this is my code:

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      print("main");
      return MaterialApp(title: 'Provider Example', initialRoute: '/', routes: {
        '/': (context) => Home(),
        'home': (context) => Home(),
      });
    }
  }

  class Home extends StatelessWidget {
    Home() {
      print("home");
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('home'),
          ),
          body: Stack(overflow: Overflow.visible, children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
                top: 40,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("text1"),
                        Text("text2",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2),
                        Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 50, horizontal: 20),
                            child: PageView(
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    color: Colors.yellow,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                        Text("hola"),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(color: Colors.blue)
                                ])),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
          ]));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Instead of Container wrapping a PageView try with an Expanded widget

Comment: @EdwynZN not works.. https://i.imgur.com/ddLXZS6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your expanded widget into a SingleChildScrollView()

Answer (score 0):

Remove the SingleChildScrollView and use the code below with Expanded:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("text1"),
    Text("text2", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.6,
        margin:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 20),
        child: PageView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: ListView(          //ListView to scroll the content
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(              //just to center the widgets inside the ListView
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                      Text("hola"),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.blue),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, it works. but the scroll only works for the yellow part. I wanted to make it work for the whole screen, I don't want the texts that say "text1" "text2" to be fixed

Comment: so you want all pages in the page view to be the same height?

Comment: What I want is to scroll through all the content on the page. As well as this, the texts I told you are fixed.

Comment: But you want the page view to expand based on the content inside? The main problem is the PageView inside the SingleChildScrollView, based on what you want to achieve i can recomment other approach.

Comment: Thank you very much crack.,Instead of having the scroll inside the pageView, I would like it to be at the general level of the page. I don't want to scroll only on the pageview.

Comment: If you really need the PageView widget in the tree, set the height will be required. You can set the height in the Container based on the widgets of the page, for example: **height: 65.0 * 17.0,** (65 widgets in the Column), but you need to know the height that the widgets will occupy.

Comment: I absolutely need the pageView .. but my content is dynamic. As I told you, I don't know how to calculate the height.

Comment: The PageView needs to act as a window that shows the content of the pages, and the window needs a fixed height to each page to be shown with the same size. If you give a fixed height to the PageView you can use it inside a SingleChildScrollView, and then scroll just the content inside the page. But changing the size of the pageview without knowing its content is something that for now I haven't seen any example, but if I find it I will modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you need to wrap your `PageView` in a parent with a size or it will be expanded in a infinity way, so you can wrap that widget inside a [LimitedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LimitedBox-class.html) or a [ConstrainedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html), for example try the next:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('home'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned.fill(
            top: 40,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("text1"),
                    Text("text2", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 50,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                      child: ConstrainedBox(
                        //Add a constrained box to wrap your widget
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          //Give it a max height you think you will use
                          maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 2,
                        ),
                        child: PageView(
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              child: Column(
                                //make your column occupy only the necessary space
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                  Text("hola"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(color: Colors.blue)
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I thank you for your time. Is it a good way? `maxHeight` I will never know how much information will be loaded dynamically. where i should locate the scroll, i am getting this problem:  https://i.imgur.com/oitIhkT.jpg

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer and added all the build method.

Comment: Thank you very much, I like how it works, but the problem is in the `maxHeight` depending on the value my elements are separated more. As I told you, I do not know how to calculate how many elements will be displayed, they can be thousands.

Comment: for example:                           maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 10,

Comment: In that case, if you don't really need the *PageView*, remove it and use a *ListView* instead of a *Column*, the problem with the column is that it will expand as much as your list grows, and that will give you a bad performance.

Comment: if i need the pageview then i need to swipe the screens.

Comment: In that case you can use your `PageView` over your `SingleChildScrollView` or you can calculate  the maxHeight with something like: `maxHeight: estimatedSize * data.length`, but if you have many data is not a good idea, more if you use images inside each item.